# What should the direction (a.ka sign) of torque be on this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, torque, statics

[image]

Ok, two sticks on a wall (Morin, 2.36), same mass density, let $F_x$ be horizontal component of the force on the upper hinge and $F_y$ it's vertical component, we could from there calculate what these should be, but I'm more interested in the direction (their sign) they take when calculating the torque of the upper stick around its bottom end, if I decide the direction of $F_y$ perpendicular to stick to be the "positive" direction, then the $F_x$ component should be negative or positive? the force of gravity on the stick $\rho\frac{L}{\cos(\theta)}g$ perpendicular to it should be positive or negative?

If $F_x$ is positive and gravity is negative I get the equation:
$$F_yL+F_xL\tan(\theta)-\rho\frac{L}{\cos(\theta)}g\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)=0$$ which seems to be the incorrect equation for torque since it doesn't lead me to the correct answer, the answer should have $-F_xL\tan(\theta)$, but I can't understand why, am I wrong or the problem solution? (or maybe I'm missing something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F_y$ on the upper hinge is positive, then you have chosen the +y axis as down (assuming x and y are horizontal and vertical). With a right handed system, +z is into the page. The y component of force from the hinge acting on the slanted stick would give a clockwise torque about the lower end of the stick. That would be represented by a torque vector in the +z direction.  The x component of the force from the hinge acting on the stick would give a CCW torque with a vector in the -z direction. The weight of the rod would also produce a CCW torque. To get the components of each force which is perpendicular to the stick you should be multiplying by sines or cosines.

Answer (score 1):

This is up my street because I’m a structural engineer. My first question to you is “is this a problem of jointed rods – a pin-jointed structure?” because if any of the three joints is rigid then the structure is not statically determinate i.e. you cannot solve it by statics alone but need to consider the elastic properties of the members. I assume that it is pin-jointed because otherwise  the answer wouldn’t be the simple one you have quoted.

When you say “torque” I assume you mean moment because torque or torsional moment is normally a twisting moment about the central axis of a member. And when you say “torque of the upper stick around its bottom end” I also assume you don’t mean bending moment in the “stick” because (I assume) it is pin-jointed and therefore won’t experience any at its end.

Assuming that the members both have the same properties and the density ρ is mass per unit length, then  the total vertical load will be $ρg(L+L/cosθ)$ Therefore the moment about the wall $= ρg(L+L/cosθ).L/2 = ρg(L^2+L^2/cosθ)/2$. I would take this to be positive as it is clockwise. This is resisted by a couple from the horizontal reactions at the wall $= [ρg(L^2+L^2/cosθ)/2]/Ltanθ = ρg(L/tanθ+L/sinθ)/2$ and the applied forces are of course equal and opposite, I would describe these as positive at the upper hinge and negative at the lower. Therefore $Fx = ρg(L/tanθ+L/sinθ)/2$ (acting in the positive x direction).

Note that half of the load of the bottom member is taken on the bottom support (I think that’s quite clear) therefore all of the remaining vertical load must be taken on the top support.

Therefore $Fy = -ρg(L/2+L/cosθ)$ (negative because it acts down).
Now your given answer is $-Fx$ times $Ltanθ$. If I substitute in $Fx$ from above, I get $-ρg(L/2+L/2cosθ)$, not $-ρg(L/2+L/cosθ)$. So to get your given answer of $–FxLtanθ$ only half of the vertical load from both members goes to the upper support. That’s not correct. All of the load from the upper member and half of that from the lower member is taken by the upper support.